# Control chart constants

Tags: notation, quality-control

When calculating Upper Control Limit (UCL) and Lower Control Limit (LCL) in control charts I use constants from http://web.uni-plovdiv.bg/kiril/Students/Masters-MYK/table_of_control_chart_constants.pdf

But why are they named $A_2,A_3,d_2,D_3,D_4,B_3,B_4$? I can't figure out how the subscripts are related.

## Edit

I can't see what the specific numbers indicate. Why not write $A_1$, $d_1$, $D_1$, $D_2$, etc, for example? I have just learned when to use which constants but I guess there is a reason for using those specific subscripts.

Comment: I think the naming is mostly just a convention, although there may be a little bit of a system in them: lower index means upper rather than lower control limit, or has to do with lower moments of the stochastic quantities involved (e.g. $d_3$ also exists). A lot of applied domains have such conventions, like "the Greeks" in financial mathematics, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)

Comment: Even if a canonical answer is hard to know for sure(the origins of some notation seems basically random), at least a partial answer could be to consider how the notation developed historically. Have the same symbols always been used since the control chart was first developed, or popularised?

Comment: <rant> I have to say "closed as a duplicate" and "closed as unclear" by people who simply aren't familiar with the subject are really annoying.  It would be like someone who has no understanding of statistics in any realm going around closing questions on here because they don't understand any of them.</rant>  Quite simply, most modern applications only use a portion of the factors that exist.  My copy of Montgomery's _Introduction to Statistical Quality Control_ contains $A$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $c_4$, $B_3$, $B_4$, $B_5$,$B_6$, $d_2$, $d_3$, $D_1$, $D_2$, $D_3$, and $D_4$.

Comment: E.B. Ferrell in 1958 proposed $A_4$, $d_4$, $D_5$ and $D_6$ with his paper "Control Charts.for Log-Normal Universes" in _Industrial Quality Control_.  It seems that there was a lot more rhyme and reason to the factors and their numbering that has not been perpetuated since Shewhart proposed his methods in the early 1930s.  Sadly, I do not have the archival information at the moment to provide a complete answer.